# Restricting sub-class declaration

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have an application where I want all my model classes to implement a specific `update` method. For this I created an `abstract class` and an `interface` with the following declaration:

```
public interface BaseInterface<T>
{
    T update(T t);
}

public abstract class BaseClass<T extends BaseClass<T>> implements BaseInterface<T>
{

}
```

Hence all my model classes will extend `BaseClass`. For example a `Book` class definition will be

```
public class Book extends BaseClass<Book>
{
    public Book update(Book b)
    {
        //implementation
    }
}
```

However using the above construct I am not able to restrict declarations of my model classes. For example while it is valid and required for the `Book` class to extend `BaseClass<Book>`, the following declaration also valid:

```
class Book extends BaseClass<User>
{
    public User update(User u)
    {
        //implementation
    }
}
```

While it is syntactically correct to do the above I want to restrict that.

**Basically I want my model classes' `update` method to take as parameter an instance of its own class and return an instance of its own class and nothing else.**

**In other words, if there is a class `C` that extends `BaseClass`, then its `update` method must be of the exact signature `C update(C c)`.**

**Or in other words if there is a class `C` that extends `BaseClass`, then the template parameter for `BaseClass` must be `C` itself [ie `C extends BaseClass<C>`] and nothing else.**

How do I achieve that?

NOTE: This is somewhat similar to the `enum` declaration

```
public class Enum<E extends Enum<E>> implements Comparable<E>
{
    int compareTo(E e)
    {
    }
}
```

Here we are able to restrict the definition of `compareTo` method to take an instance of its own type of `enum` and not any other kind of `enum`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please for the love of god please don't create an interface called `BaseInterface`, you might as well call it `Zywbxzytdkkenbfd`. It should be called `Updateable`.

Comment: I named the interface BaseInterface to make my question clear. Not that I will use it in production.

Answer (score 2):

Change definition of you interface to `interface BaseInterface<T extends BaseClass<T>>`.

Please follow my example:

```
public interface BaseInterface<T extends BaseClass<T>> {
    T update(T t);
}

public abstract class BaseClass<T extends BaseClass<T>> implements
        BaseInterface<T> {

}

public class Book extends BaseClass<Book> {
    @Override
    public Book update(Book b) {
        return null;
    }
}

class User {}

    // This code cannot be compiled exactly for reason you want.
public class Book2 extends BaseClass<User> {
    @Override
    public Book2 update(Book2 b) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think, the above code does quite what I want. The coder for `Book2` can easily refactor the `update` method to `User update(User u)` and the code compiles. What I want is that if there is a class `C`, then its update method must be `C update(C c)`

Comment: Try it as I did. The code cannot be compiled anywayt because class User does not meet requirement: it does not extend BaseClass. So, the compilation error appears in the class header.

Comment: @Swaranga Sarma: You can enforce that a subclass defines a specific method. But you cannot prevent the subclass from defining overloaded versions of this method.

Comment: @Alex...but if User extends BaseClass, it compiles.